# Bootstrap Navigation Doesn't Come Out Right

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have a bootstrap navigation like this [one](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar)

But this is in a ROR application and it keeps stacking no matter what I do.

So I decided to create a simple HTML file to see what I'm missing here.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
         <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
         <ul class="nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

But if you copy and paste that code, all you'll see is everything stacking instead of being a horizontal menu like in the link above.

What ON EARTH am I doing wrong here?!?!??!?!?!

**EDIT**
The navigation above is totally ripped off from bootstrap page as linked above.

Comment: You are using bootstrap 3.3.4 but referring to the docs of bootstrap 2.3.2. [This is the updated documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: @AbM, dude! Thank you so much! If you want to have it accepted, make it an answer, and I'll happily accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bootstrap 3.3.4 but referring to the docs of bootstrap 2.3.2. [This is the updated documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Answer (score 2):

You're using the [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) docs but including the [3.3.4 files](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) and then you're trying to make a [2.3.2 navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar) (which does not work).

Using [Bootstrap 3.3.4 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), your navbar code should look like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Otherwise, if you were intending to use the 2.3.2 docs you need to fix your 3 included files...

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hey thank you for your answer! it was very through! I appreciate it. I've upvoted it since I told the other person that I'm accepting their answer.